# Schema.org properties suitable for General Web-services page array?

Tags: schema.org

Given the fact the "Web programming", "Web design", or "SEO" doesn't exist as Schema.org properties, what are the properties suitable for major [fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(computer_science)) in webpage in the context of "Web programmign", "Web design" or "SEO" ?

Comment: It depends on what you want to say about/with this. Do you want to give information about Web design in general, do you want to offer Web design services, is "Web design" a category in your blog, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For terms not belonging to Schema.org's standard make use of `sameAs`:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ProfessionalService">
<a itemprop="sameAs" link="http://dbpedia.org/page/Search_engine_optimization" />
</div>
```